# Chrome extension: content_scripts doesn't call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making chrome addon. And I have problem now.
content_scripts doesn't call at all.
Any idea?

This is my `manifest.json`.

```
{
"manifest_version":2,
"name":"ABC",
"version":"0.0.1",
"permissions":["tabs"],
"background":{
   "scripts":["js/background.js"],
   "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts":[
 {
   "matches":["<all_urls>"],
   "js":["js/contents.js"]
 }
],
"browser_action":{
  "default_popup":"templates/popup.html"
}
}
```

And this is my `js/contents.js`. just wrote `console.log`.

```
console.log("Atleast reached contents.js")
```

--

Added console
[image]

Comment: Looks fine so far, is js/contents.js definitely in the right place / named correctly?

Comment: @OscarW yes, that's definitely correct though... and js/background.js in same directly works fine.

Comment: Make sure you've reloaded the extension on chrome://extensions page and the web page itself. Note, the new tab or built-in UI pages of the browser can't run content scripts. Neither extension pages as the content scripts are only for the web pages. Also, check if your console has filters applied or levels altered (in the toolbar).

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried it. but, still not work.. I added console image.

Comment: Like I said, the content scripts don't run in extension pages. You don't need a content script here. Content scripts are for web pages. You need a normal script that you can load with a `<script src=.....>` tag in your popup.html. See [the architecture article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview).